# Provable security with over-computing power

Tags: provable-security

Suppose we are trying to construct a cryptographic scheme, say public key encryption, and I can prove the IND-CPA security of the PKE scheme when any adversaries perform at least $T$ queries. That is, our proof only holds when the number of ciphertexts allowed by an adversary is bigger than at least $T$.

In other words, if the number of queries is smaller than $T$, our proof has a huge gap.

I think that this situation might exist in a hybrid of games.

If the proof is true, then is this proof valid since an adversary has an over-computing power? I was trying to construct a reduction, but it was not easy at least for me.

Comment: @fgrieu I want a situation where the proof only works under the assumption that the number of ciphertexts that an adversary has is "bigger" than $T$.  You mean that this situation is trivial, right? I wonder about the situation since some proof does not work when empty queries are allowed.

Comment: Let A be a successful adversary making t<T queries. Construct adversary B, that simply runs A, and before outputting A's output makes T-t random queries. B now makes at least T queries while having the same success probability as A. QED

Comment: Thanks for the answer!